# BiometricPrompt returns false error code 11 (ERROR_NO_BIOMETRICS) in some Samsung devices

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

`BiometricPrompt.authenticate()` function returns error code 11 (ERROR_NO_BIOMETRICS) in some Samsung devices like A20s (android 9) meanwhile user has enrolled fingerprint and also `canAuthenticate(Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK)` returns 0 (BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS) means device biometric hardware is available and enrolled.

I'm using library version `'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha03'`

any solutions?

Comment: Not all Samsung devices meet requirements, apparently. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142150327#comment17 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141918357#comment2

Comment: @CommonsWare  think these issues you mentioned are about face scan/iris scanner not fingerprint.
fingerprint sensor should meet the requirements, am I right?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. If you wanted, you could create a project that reproduces your problem and file your own issue on that tracker, including the project and the specific Samsung models that give you `ERROR_NO_BIOMETRICS`. My general point is that they apparently do some sort of allowlist/denylist stuff, and perhaps your devices are getting the results that they are because of that logic.

Comment: @CommonsWare FYI issued solved by an android system update. from android 9 to 10.